# How to Plot graph by defining a transcendental equation in the function

Tags: plotting, functions

I need to plot k0 against b where b is determined by the roots of the transcendental equation u*Tan[u]=b and k0=u^2. I typed as shown in the attached image.[image: Mathematica file]
But I did not get.
Please help me getting the required plot.

Comment: 1. Please show us the code text rather than the screenshot of it. 2. Please check the document of `ParametricPlot`.

Comment: "b is determined by the roots of the transcendental equation u*Tan[u]=b". Did you mean `u[b]` is determined as the root of `u*Tan[u]=b` ?

Answer (score 4):

```
$Version

(* "13.1.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]
```

As recommended by @xzczd, use [`ParametricPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricPlot.html)

```
ParametricPlot[
 {u*Tan[u], u^2}, {u, 0, 1.429},
 PlotRange -> All,
 Frame -> True,
 AspectRatio -> 1,
 FrameLabel ->
  (Style[#, 14] & /@ {b, Subscript[k, 0]}),
 ColorFunction ->
  Function[{x, y, u}, ColorData["Rainbow"][u]],
 PlotLegends ->
  Placed[BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {0, 1.429}},
    LegendLabel -> Style[HoldForm[u], 14]],
   {.75, .4}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

`ParametricPlot` and `ParametricRegion` are, indeed, nice approaches. One can also use series methods—such as `PadeApproximant`—to get *analytic* approximations.

I've posted my solution as a Cloud Notebook [here](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/abbott/Published/Community/TranscendentalSolution.nb).

Comment: For other types of rational approximations there is also the Function Approximation package [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FunctionApproximations/tutorial/FunctionApproximations.html). Those functions have been made resource functions see [here](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/search/?i=rational) and the related resources at the end for the other functions.

Answer (score 2):

If we want to limit `{b,0,10}` and `{k0,2,2}`, we can use `ParametricRegion`.

```
k0 = u^2;
b = u*Tan[u];
reg = ParametricRegion[{b, k0}, {u}];
Region[reg, PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {0, 2}}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
 BaseStyle -> Red, Axes -> True, TicksStyle -> Blue]
```

[image]